# How to bring two object in the same level in laravel json output?

Tags: json, laravel, api, formatting, parameter-passing

I have two model named Student and Roll. I want to the data of them so that they remains in the same level.
The controller part..

```
   $stuents=Student::all();
   $count=$stuents->count();
   $rolls=Roll::all();
   $response=[];
   for($i=0;$i<$count;$i++){
        $response[$i]=[
        'students'=>$stuents[$i],
        'roll_number'=>$rolls[$i]
        ];
   }
   return response($response);
```

The output of the above response..

```
[
{
    "students": {
        "name": "habib",
        "dept": "ece"
    },
    "roll": 1609047
},
{
    "students": {
        "name": "hafiz",
        "dept": "ece"
    },
    "roll": 1609061
}  

]
```

But my expected output will be..

```
[
{
    "students": {
        "name": "habib",
        "dept": "ece",
        "roll": 1609047
    }
},
{
    "students": {
        "name": "hafiz",
        "dept": "ece",
        "roll": 1609061
    }
}
]
```

How can I solve this problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You would have to be adding the role to each student that you are adding to the response array.

If objects in `$students`:

```
for ($i = 0; $i < $count; $i++) {
    // if object
    $students[$i]->roll = $rolls[$i];

    $response[] = [
        'student' => $students[$i],
    ];
}
```

If arrays in `$students`:

```
for ($i = 0; $i < $count; $i++) {
    $response[] = [
        'student' => ['roll' => $rolls[$i]] + $students[$i],
    ];
}
```